# Getting started with R

Tags: r, machine-learning, references

I have access to a database with a lot of credit data about individuals through my job and I'd like to use it to learn some R and eventually, come up with some models that predict credit worthiness using both the credit data and positive data from how these clients perform as our customers.

Can someone recommend a few things:

- Some tutorials and/or resources for getting started with R
- Good entry-level use cases for how I could use this credit data to learn R

Comment: "Some tutorials and/or resources for getting started with R": [Learning R. Where does one Start?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3375808/583830), [What are some good books, web resources, and projects for learning R?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/420296/583830), [R for finance tutorials and resources](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1228801/583830).

Comment: But, also, GIYF

Comment: In parallel with understanding techniques for data analysis, with credit data (and any other sort of data) it is very important to understand the real story behind the data, e.g. bank loans can be marked as over drawn if one misses a payment by a day but they don't become NPL (Non-performing Loan) until 90-days - it is important to understand the influence of this lag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Recently I asked for a set of links to start learning R. Glad to share it with you:

- very-very short intro http://stat.ethz.ch/education/semesters/ss2011/CompStat/R_Tutorial.pdf
- http://www.cyclismo.org/tutorial/R/
- http://math.illinoisstate.edu/dhkim/rstuff/rtutor.html
- and a very good book: http://math.illinoisstate.edu/dhkim/rstuff/rtutor.html

What I would suggest you to start with is...

- just simple playing with the data: plotting histograms, scatterplots, boxplots, etc.
- better understanding your data: density estimation, detecting outliers, etc.
- then maybe trying to explore the connection between the variables: regression, linear models, variable selection, non parametrical models, etc.
- testing different models: cross validation, bootstrap, confidence intervals
- and a lot more ideas limited only with your imagination...

Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Here are some more links

**Computing for Data Analysis**

This course is about learning the fundamental computing skills necessary for effective data analysis. You will learn to program in R and to use R for reading data, writing functions, making informative graphs, and applying modern statistical methods.

https://www.coursera.org/course/compdata

**Fundamentals of Statistical Computing for Behavioral and Social Scientists** 
&
**Introduction to R with Applications in Data Mining**

http://people.virginia.edu/~js6ew/#Courses

And once you learn a lot R

**useR! 2013, the R user conference**

www3.uclm.es/congresos/useR-2013/